# Newly Added Files Getting Permissions Error

Tags: apache, file-permissions, wampserver, http-status-code-403

I'm running a local WAMP server and have just batch-processed a bunch of images in Photoshop, automatically saving them to a directory.  When I try to access these images from my browser, I get a 403 error.

This has not yet happened to me on this server, though I have not yet done any batch processing.

I'm running Windows 7 Professional, and I've tried giving full-access to all users across-the-board for these images, but I'm still getting this same Apache error.  Here's what my logs look like:

`[Tue Sep 27 15:02:37 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (OS 5)Access is denied.  : file permissions deny server access: C:/wamp/www/site/img/4142.jpg, referer: http://site.local/index.html`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out Windows was encrypting these files for some reason.  This is what helped me solve this:

> I noticed that all my file-names in Explorer were written in Green.
>   After a bit of digging around, it turns out they were encrypted, so I
>   turned encryption off on them and everything's good now!
>
> In order to disable decryption, select your files, right-click and go
>   to properties, and under "General" go to "Advanced" and remove the
>   tick that says "Encrypt File Contents". The file-names will then turn
>   back to black, and everything was fine

Source:  http://www.wampserver.com/phorum/read.php?2,43642

Comment: Just had the same problem after dropping in bootstrap. Thanks for saving me a couple hours of headache.